# A single word that describes the moment a person realizes they are dreaming?

Tags: single-word-requests

*Lucid dreams* is a phrase to describe the state of someone knowing that they are dreaming.  What I am looking for is a single word that describes that ***moment*** of realization.  A friend suggested *lucidity*, but its definition doesn't quite fit right for what I am seeking.

Comment: The guys at [cogsci.se] may know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use [*anagnorisis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagnorisis), which is the moment in a Greek narrative when the protagonist has a sudden realization of their true identity.

Comment: This is the perfect fit.  I selected this as the answer because, as defined in Merriam-Webster and other sources, it describes the point at which a person not only gains recognition of their identity, but also their ***situation***.  Bravo and excellent research. For extra credit, what would the proper, or otherwise creative uses of this term be? 'I reached a point of anagnorisis.', 'I anagnorisized and I was not longer disturbed by the unfolding events.', 'The best lucid dreams occur when I reach anagnorisis early on.', etc.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how specialized moments of realization are in English. Using words that just mean that (in varied forms):

- realization
- discovery
- awakening
- aware
- epiphany
- eureka
- click — "And then it clicked: I was dreaming!"

I am unable to think of a word that is reserved for a special *subject* of realization. Different terms have their typical uses but I think the emotional feeling or suddenness is more of a deciding factor.

Answer (score 2):

The verb form of "surface" may be appropriate. It seems to capture the notion of partial emergence without complete exit.

Answer (score 2):

Epiphany --> moment of realization

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphany_(feeling)

Answer (score 2):

You could call it a *moment of lucidity*.

eg.

> I was flying, I saw the sheep in the field below me. Then, a moment of lucidity, this was but just a dream, and none of this was real.

Answer (score 0):

I like "quicken" or "quickening."

The first moment of realization of a lucid dream is, to me, not unlike a feeling of rebirth. So, I think it would be appropriate to describe the sensation using a word which means "the first movements of a fetus."

Answer (score 0):

Not direct answers, but they may help in your quest:

- *Hypnagogia* — the state between being awake & asleep (Greek for "to lead away", [ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypnagogia))
- *Hypnopompic* — the state between being asleep & awake
- *Somniferous* — sleep inducing

Check the Wikipedia reference, there are tons of articles on sleep that may help you find your word.

I like "awakening" but it could be misleading on its own.

Answer (score 0):

***emerging***?

in a sense similar to emergence phenomena attributed to anaesthetic medications.