# Word for realizing reality?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say a person's reality sucks and he starts living in a fantasy but time to time again he realizes the reality,  his status,  his real image in front of other people.  What would this realization be called?

The closest word I can think of is  becoming *self-conscious*.

Any other word you would like to suggest

Comment: Related questions: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21943/a-single-word-that-describes-the-moment-a-person-realizes-they-are-dreaming/151301#151301, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27675/is-there-a-specific-word-for-jolted-from-naïveté/27679#27679, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91208/word-for-seeing-someone-s-moment-of-realization, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226595/is-there-a-single-word-for-becoming-lucid

Comment: Thanks but these do not contain the word that I am looking for.

Comment: self-conscious means  "uncomfortably nervous about or embarrassed by what other people think about you".

Comment: When you fantasize about something, you are in a dreamlike state. To get out of this state, you sometimes need a good *wake-up call* or a *reality check*.

Comment: *ground-hogging the Matrix*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"getting real"** seems to be the idiom you're looking for.

> - [**Getting real**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=get%20real) is the act of giving yourself a reality check.
> - When someone tells you to [**get real**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=get%20real), they want you to get a reality check and to stop behaving as though you're living in a fantasy world.

- Hey, it's time you got real.
- You think you'll win the lottery if you buy one ticket a week? Get real!
- Get real! He's never going to give you the money.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about the adjective *[disillusioned](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disillusioned)*?

> - disappointed and unhappy because of discovering the truth about something or someone that you liked or respected: - *He's become a disillusioned man.
>     All the other teachers are thoroughly disillusioned with their colleague.*

Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You could say this person had a flash of [***self-awareness***](http://thefreedictionary.com/self-awareness), meaning they became conscious of their own character and position in life. You could even say that they had a sudden [***epiphany***](http://thefreedictionary.com/epiphany), or moment of insight, that brought upon a flash of ***self-awareness***.